# How can I start exploring about IBM Edge Server?

Tags: websphere

I need to start installing and understanding IBM Edge Server for load balancing, but I am not able to find proper documentation on it. can some one please help with a better documentation where i can learn about its installation/configuration and testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The admin guide is a good general starting point.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.edge.doc/lb/welcome_lbipv6.html